# Is it safe for a javascript to overwrite itself using File.write()?

Tags: javascript, adobe, extendscript

This is a javascript for Adobe ExtendScript. Basically I want to have a persistent variable in the script to store a user's preferences, like you can with an AppleScript `property`. The only way I could think of was for the script to overwrite itself with `File.write()`.

```
var MY_PROPERTY = true;

function reassignProperty(propName, propValue) {
    var thisFile = new File($.fileName);

    if (thisFile.open("r")) {
        var myScript = thisFile.read();
        thisFile.close();

        // Look for the property declaration and overwrite with new value
        var searchStr = new RegExp("(var " + propName + " = )" + ".+");
        var newScript = myScript.replace(searchStr, "$1" + propValue + ";");

        thisFile.open("w");
        thisFile.write(newScript);
        thisFile.close();
    }
}

reassignProperty("MY_PROPERTY", "false");
```

As far as I could tell, this worked. But is it safe? My gut instinct tells me there should be a cleaner way to have persistent variables, but if there isn't, I just want to know if there are any potential problems with a self-overwriting script.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Adobe ExtendScript, but usually you would store the user's preferences in a separate file and then read that file when the program starts.

Comment: he's trying to update a users preference in that separate file.

Comment: Really? Saying "overwrite itself" doesn't sound like a separate file. Basically, I would never recommend modifying a script file while it is running, but go ahead and make whatever modifications you want to a script file that isn't currently running.

Comment: With these Adobe scripts, I'm sort of assuming you wouldn't want an external settings file unless you could hide it somewhere in a standard place to put such things, or else it would visibly add clutter to the user's Scripts panel. I'd like to know what the potential downsides of self-overwriting are so I can weigh it against the advantages (i.e. simpler script and no clutter).

Answer (score 0):

It's almost certainly going to be a bad design decision to include the ability for a program to replace itself. First off you'd have a difficulties because the current thread of execution differs from the file that's supposed to be running, so you'd definitely get side-effects.

Basically your asking for confusion, and confusion is bad. You should use an external file to store the data, or just hold the info in a variable or field of HTML.